Effect of COMPONENT OF constraint on extensibility
Given the following schema, I contend that ConstrainedContentSequence is not extensible, does not allow values having more than 8 Content values, and that a value of type ConstrainedContentSequence would be encoded in PER without an extension bit.  A colleague finds this surprising because the added constraint is aimed at the component type of the SEQUENCE OF, not at the SEQUENCE OF itself, and yet the extensibility on the SEQUENCE OF type is removed.  Technically, however, the added constraint is a constraint on the SEQUENCE OF; it just has the effect of constraining the component values.
We're looking to verify the above contention is correct (that we aren't missing something).
The definitions:
Content ::= INTEGER(1..16)
ContentSequence ::= SEQUENCE (SIZE(1..8, ...)) OF Content
ConstrainedContentSequence ::= ContentSequence (WITH COMPONENT (1..7))

We believe it is clause X.680 50.11 that removes the extensibility.  Thus, we believe ConstrainedContentSequence is equivalent to:
SEQUENCE (SIZE(1..8)) OF INTEGER(1..7)

and NOT:
SEQUENCE (SIZE(1..8, ...)) OF INTEGER(1..7)

X.680 50.11:

If a subtype constraint is serially applied to a parent type which is extensible through the application of an extensible constraint, value notation used within it shall not reference values that are not in the extension root of the parent type. The result of the second (serially applied) constraint is defined to be the same as if the constraint had been applied to the parent type without its extension marker and possible extension additions.


I think that is equivalent to:
ConstrainedContentSequence ::= SEQUENCE SIZE(1..8, ...) OF INTEGER(1..7)

Reason: Dubuisson has:
TextBlock ::= SEQUENCE of VisibleString
AddressBlock ::= TextBlock (WITH COMPONENT (SIZE(1..32)))

is equivalent to:
AddressBlock ::= SEQUENCE of VisibleString (SIZE(1..32))

and also:
IntegerMatrix ::= SEQUENCE SIZE(6) OF SEQUENCE SIZE(6) OF INTEGER
CoordinateMatrix ::= IntegerMatrix (WITH COMPONENT (WITH COMPONENT (-100..100)))

equivalent to:
CoordinateMatrix ::= SEQUENCE SIZE (6) OF SEQUENCE SIZE (6) OF INTEGER (-100..100)

So it can apply to size and value constraints, depending. But it seems to be reaching into the constructed type, not operating on the 'shell' of the constructed type itself.
Best bet - shove it into your fav (and complete) asn1 compiler, see what the generated code looks like, especially the deserialiser where you should be able to see the constraints expressed in the code.
Dubuisson also says that this subtype constraint has no influence on how BER or PER encodes a SEQUENCE OF or SET OF. He also says that the constraint applies to the type of the elements of the parent type, i.e. the type that appears after SEQUENCE OF or SET OF. In your case, the type after SEQUENCE OF is Content.

Thanks.  Those examples show how the WITH COMPONENT applies, but don't address the extensibility.  I updated the question with some additional information regarding why we think what we do.

@Kevin, I'm pretty sure the extensibility doesn't come into it. Dubuisson is clear that WITH COMPONENT applies to the type that comes after SEQUENCE OF. Your extensible constraint is part of the SEQUENCE OF, and therefore out of the scope of the WITH COMPONENT.

You are correct that X.680 50.11 indicates that the resulting ConstrainedContentSequence does not have an extensible SIZE constraint since the serial application of subtype constraints removes extensibility.  Note that if Content had an extensible constraint, the WITH COMPONENT would not affect how it is encoded as far as extensibility goes.  This means that if you did not want to affect the extensibility of ContentSequence, you would need to put the "WITH COMPONENT(S)" constraint on the type that contains ContentSequence instead.  This way ContentSequence would not lose its extensibility since the serial application of constraints would be on its parent instead.
